# replace `iframe` in html with a simple jpg

Tags: html, css, iframe, hugo, toml

A pre-built Hugo website template I have has an `iframe` (from Google Maps) in the HTML of one of its pages.

```
                    <div class="map">
                        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?...."
                            width="100%" height="400" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe> 
                    </div>
```

The layout of the resulting webpage is exactly my desired output, but I would like to replace the `iframe` with a static jpg.

The static jpg I would like to link to is on a different page (but part of the same pre-built Hugo template site), which seems to be generated by a *.toml file:

```
[params.about]
image   = "images/about/photo1.jpg"
```

Unfortunately, I do not know any HTML nor any toml. Is there any easy way for me to replace the `iframe` with the jpg?

Or if it's not as easy as a simple cut and paste, are there some particular aspects of HTML that I should read up on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not the best answer, but if anyone is looking for a workaround to this sort of a question, this is what I did.

I ended up uploading the jpg to imgur and then changing the `iframe` tags with a simple `img` tag:

```
                    <div class="map">
                        <img src="https://www.imgur.com/...."
                            width="100%" height="400" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></img> 
                    </div>
```

If anyone has a better solution, so that I don't have to refer to the `src=` from a website like imgur, I'd be all ears. I suppose I could try to work out the relative path of where the images are kept, but I'm not sure how to go back up a directory tree.